# How to test that PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase fails when an expected exception is not produced

Tags: unit-testing, exception, phpunit

I am trying to extend the functionality of PHPUnit.

I want to extend its behaviour regarding how it allows tests to assert that an expected `Exception` is thrown.

I have done this by extending `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, like so:

```
class Improved_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    //...
}
```

The problem is, I now need to write a test that shows that a test will fail if the `@expectedException` is not thrown.

For example, I want to show that the following test would fail:

```
/**
 * I want to write a TestTest that passes when these tests would fail
 */
class FooTest extends Improved_TestCase {

    /**
     * @expectedException Exception
     */
    function testFooThrowsAnnotatedException()
    {
        Foo::thisWillNotThrowAnException();
    }

    function testFooThrowsSetException()
    {
        $this->setExpectedException('Exception');

        Foo::thisWillNotThrowAnException();
    }

}
```

The above tests should fail. But some how **I need to write a test that will pass when the above tests fails**.

I have tried looking through [PHPUnit's tests source code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/3a3c2cab477cd47ef6295de62c321a0b107a7480/tests), but I don't understand how or where it tests the working of expected exception tests.

From what I can tell, my best guess is that the [`@expectedException` behaviour is tested here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/c970b9ed01302c7ed5ef14bf5cb2936415ad42f5/tests/_files/ExceptionTest.php), but it doesn't make sense, because those tests would **fail** if PHPUnit is working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

The code that tests it is [here in TestCaseTest.php](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/c970b9ed01302c7ed5ef14bf5cb2936415ad42f5/tests/Framework/TestCaseTest.php):

```
function testException()
{
    $test = new ThrowExceptionTestCase('test');
    $test->setExpectedException('RuntimeException');

    $result = $test->run();

    $this->assertEquals(1, count($result));
    $this->assertTrue($result->wasSuccessful());
}    

public function testNoException()
{
    $test = new ThrowNoExceptionTestCase('test');
    $test->setExpectedException('RuntimeException');

    $result = $test->run();

    $this->assertEquals(1, $result->failureCount());
    $this->assertEquals(1, count($result));
}
```